# How to generate table rows based on data in database

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to take this style of code and generate based on how many machines are returned from the database.

I have this:

```
 <table style="width: 100%; height:85%;table-layout:fixed;text-align:center;">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $array[0]; ?> <span class="blue">#1</span><br>
    sets <span class="blue">1</span> reps <span class="blue">50</span><br>
    weight <span class="blue">25</span></td>
    <td><?php echo $array[1]; ?> <span class="blue">#2</span><br>
    sets <span class="blue">1</span> reps <span class="blue">100</span><br>
    weight <span class="blue">40</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $array[2]; ?> <span class="blue">#3</span><br>
    sets <span class="blue">2</span> reps <span class="blue">25</span><br>
    weight <span class="blue">20</span></td>
    <td><?php echo $array[3]; ?> <span class="blue">#4</span><br>
    sets <span class="blue">3</span> reps <span class="blue">25</span><br>
    weight <span class="blue">30</span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Here is the database code to retrieve the machines from the database:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT m1.machine_id, m2.* FROM userPlanDetail AS m1 LEFT JOIN machines AS m2 ON    m1.machine_id = m2.machine_id WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id1' AND `cardio` = 0";
$retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1, $conn );
$array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $array[] = $row['machine_name'];
}
```

I want the code to detect how many machines are in the database that aren't cardio machines and generate the number of table rows accordingly.

Here is a visual representation:

[image]

Comment: Are the numbers (#1, #2, #4, ... $7) expected to be in the output or are they there simply for us to locate the appropriate text in the image?

Comment: The numbers are expected in the output. It puts all the non cardio machines on the left, and all cardio machines on the right.

Comment: What data is in $row and in what order? I.e. m2.* returns what?

Comment: The $row will return each machine name. So inside the array, there will be 4 machines names. Although there could be more or less machines depending on the user. So i will just use a sql COUNT to count the number of non cardio machines and generate the table accordingly.

Comment: The question is what are the names of the other fields that are returned from your query in $row. Your sql is selecting "m1.machine_id, m2.*" I assume that sets, reps, and weight are part of the results set (coming from m2.*) and are not hard-coded. Could they be coming from userPlanDetail and you haven't given us the complete SQL?

Comment: Actually the sets and reps and weight is hardcoded right now. The machines table includes machine_id, machine_name,and a cardio flag indicating whether the machine is cardio or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated for hard-coded machine attributes (not really a good idea)**

```
$machine_atts = array(
    'bicep curl' => array( 'sets' => 1, 'reps' => 50, 'weight' => 25 ),
    'cable chest press' => array( 'sets' => 1, 'reps' => 100, 'weight' => 40 ),
    'lat pulldown' => array( 'sets' => 2, 'reps' => 25, 'weight' => 20 ),
    'tricep extension' => array( 'sets' => 3, 'reps' => 25, 'weight' => 30 ),
);
$sql1 = "SELECT m1.machine_id, m2.* FROM userPlanDetail AS m1 LEFT JOIN machines AS m2 ON    m1.machine_id = m2.machine_id WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id1' AND `cardio` = 0";
$retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1, $conn );
$array = array();

$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $i++;
    $sets = $machine_atts[$row['machine_name']]['sets'];
    $reps = $machine_atts[$row['machine_name']]['reps'];
    $weight = $machine_atts[$row['machine_name']]['weight'];
    $array[] = '<td>'.$row['machine_name'].'> <span class="blue">'.$i.'</span><br>sets <span class="blue">'.$sets.'</span> reps <span class="blue">'.$reps.'</span><br>weight <span class="blue">'.$weight.'</span></td>';
}

echo '<table style="width: 100%; height:85%;table-layout:fixed;text-align:center;">';
foreach ( array_chunk( $array, 2 ) as $chunk )
    echo '<tr>' . implode('', $chunk ) . '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

**Original Answer**

Assuming the number of sets, number of reps, and weight are in the results set of the query:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT m1.machine_id, m2.* FROM userPlanDetail AS m1 LEFT JOIN machines AS m2 ON    m1.machine_id = m2.machine_id WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id1' AND `cardio` = 0";
$retval1 = mysql_query( $sql1, $conn );
$array = array();

$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $i++;
    $array[] = '<td>'.$row['machine_name'].'> <span class="blue">'.$i.'</span><br>sets <span class="blue">'.$row['sets'].'</span> reps <span class="blue">'.$row['reps'].'</span><br>weight <span class="blue">'.$row['weight'].'</span></td>';
}

echo '<table style="width: 100%; height:85%;table-layout:fixed;text-align:center;">';
echo '<tr>' . implode('</tr><tr>', array_chunk( $array, 2 ) ) . '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I also don't think the implode is working. The only output i get is "ArrayArray". But when i print_r the array it gives me all the td's and it looks like everything is fine.

Comment: Yes, slight issue with implode. Corrected. :)

Comment: Would strongly suggest moving attributes to the database at some level. userPlanDetail would allow you to customize for each user.

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to put sets reps and weight in database right now. I'm just having trouble, that's why they are hardcoded. This way works great! Should i do the same thing for the cardio side?

Comment: Since cardio side is only 1 wide, you don't need to use array_chunk. In fact, you don't need the array at all. change $array[]= to echo '<tr><td>'...'</td></tr>';. Be sure to echo the table open before entering the loop and the table close after completing the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are loading all of your results into an array you can use array_chunk to break the array into rows and then output accordingly.

```
 $array = array_chunk($array, 4);
 echo '<table style="width: 100%; height:85%;table-layout:fixed;text-align:center;">';
 foreach($array as $row){
     echo "<tr>";
     foreach($row as $cell){
        // echo out your tds for format each cell here.  
     }
     echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo '</table>';
```

Comment: pretty much... just what you have in your reference markup replacing the actual values with echos of php variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    for ($x=0; $x<sizeOf($array); $x++) {
        echo '<tr><td>Array Data Here</td></tr>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?